# Why does my TSAL6200 Infrared diode have a short range

Tags: transistors, infrared

I am using a Vishay TSAL6200 Infrared diode to control a Dakin AC unit. It worked fine as long as the controller is within 4 – 6 ft of the AC unit. I would think it would have a longer range. I must have done something wrong with my design or implementation. The IR LED is driven by a 2N2222 transistor. Here is the circuit diagram.

[image]

According to the TSAL6200 datasheet the max current is .1a. I calculated the value of R2 as 5v / .1a = 50 ohm resistor.

I would have expected a range of at least 15 ft. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: use your phone camera to compare the optical output to the actual remote control

Comment: why do you believe that there is 5 V across the resistor?

Comment: Too many errors, bad assumptions and missing details on Rx, modulation . What's different from the remote that works?  Beam angle, peak current, modulation? .. also its 940 nm

Comment: @jsotola Thank you very much for your reply. I used my phone camera and the original remote is much brighter. Also, the lens on the original is clear where my IR is dark, don't know if that matters or not. Re: 5 V across the resistor - I know the voltage between the the 5v terminal on the esp and ground is 4.9 v. I don't know how to calc voltage across the resistor. I know a transistor has a voltage drop of .7v so it seems like the voltage drop across the resistor might be closer to 4.2 v. Should I calc a different resistor? I'm not an EE and am at the limit of my knowledge.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: Thanks for taking time to reply. I'm not an EE so a lot of this is at the limit of my knowledge. Your comment "Too many errors, bad assumptions and missing details on Rx, modulation" isn't helpful to me. [Here is the datasheet if that is helpful](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81010/tsal6200.pdf). What about 940 nm.

Comment: you have three components in series, yet you are thinking about a voltage drop across only two

Comment: It is not 633nm rather 940 nm.  It is not 5V/0.1A=50  rather Rs= (5V-Vf-Vce(sat))/0.1A  = (5-1.6-0.2)/0.1= 32 Ohms and your carrier f and modulation error (preamble) etc. is important

Comment: Does this AC use a standard IR carrier frequency ?? 26kHz 32 kHz?  what do you use? anything?

Comment: I'm assuming it uses a Carrier frequency http://tinyurl.com/yclvf8ub

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you for the very helpful feedback. For background info: I originally found [this](https://esp8266-shop.com/blog/esp8266-ir-remote-control-of-air-conditioners/) and it led me to [this](https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266) website that has a library for running a number of Air Conditioners. In one of the Daikin files I found the **carrier freq is 38khz**. In [this](https://harizanov.com/2012/02/control-daikin-air-conditioner-over-the-internet/) website that guy used a 940nm IR diode.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 In the next couple of days I'll replace the 50 ohm resistor with a 33 ohm one. I also noticed from the IR datasheet that a Peak forward current of 200ma can be used. Ans, a surge of 1.5A is permitted. Do you think it would be safe to switch to a 15 ohm resistor? Also, between the ESP and the base of the transistor I'm using 150 ohm resistor. Is that OK? Your simulator shows 390 ohm. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You must compute temp rise or use SOA curves based on pulse width.  Do you use a carrier clock with data? 150 =Rb is overkill, normally Ic/Ib=10 so Rb/Rc ~ 10 roughly

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - **Good news!** I replaced the 50 ohm resistor with 33 ohms and the signal reaches a good 15' now where before 6' was about it. 15' is plenty for my needs. Also, when I compare the brightness using my cell phone camera the mfg is about as bright as my IR LED. Sounds like I can switch the 150 ohm to about 330. I'll do that next time I have it apart. Yes there is a carrier freq of 38 khz. Does EE75 mean you graduated in 75? If so, I'm ME75. So this is out of my comfort zone. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes well done....